Should I use dipole correction when calculating heterostructures using Janus TMD?
In Janus TMD structures, an internal dipole moment is formed. This formed dipole moment generates an electric field throughout the cell, and if it’s a heterostructure, the electric field generated by Janus TMD will affect the other joined structures. If we use dipole correction here, the electric field generated by Janus TMD will also disappear, leading to inaccurate calculation results, don’t you think? I believe that if the vacuum space is large enough, dipole correction should not be used in Janus TMD heterostructures. I would appreciate it if you could confirm whether my thinking is correct.
I am currently doing calculations in VASP, and the vacuum region is set to 20 angstroms

You can refer to the following answer of a similar question: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/12491/1554
